# get query params in url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to obtain the following redirect:

http://xpto.com/aaaa/bbb/?gid=1&tid=2&cid=3 => http://xpto.com/?pt=nnnn&gid=1&tid=2&cid=3

I am using the following rule:

RewriteRule ^aaaa/bbb/\?(.*)$ ?pt=candidatura&$1 [L]

But it is not working.

Can someone help me?

Thanks,
ED

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the [QSA] flag.

Here it goes:

RewriteRule ^aaa/bbb/(.*) http://xpto.com/?pt=sss$1 [QSA]

Hope it helps someone.

ED